# Understanding the Difference Between DNS Resolvers

Tags: domain-name-system, linux-networking, curl, dig, docker-machine

### Intro

In the attempt to debug a networking issue local to our intranet, it became apparent that `curl` `host` `nslookup` and `dig` behave differently. Where `dig` and `host` returns the IP address of the URL in question, `curl` and `nslookup` return:

```
 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: internal.site.company.com
```

and

```
 nslookup: can't resolve 'internal.site.company.com`
```

### Context

While this should not matter, in the essence of giving more context to the problem, this issue is occurring on and behind a `docker-machine` (tested using a docker-machine on both `virtualbox` and `parallels` to be exact). The `docker-machine` and containers it hosts all have the correct IP address of the desired internal DNS server in their `/etc/resolv.conf`. The IP address of the desired URL is also reachable from the machines which cannot resolve the name. As touched on above, the address is an internal site and our DNS server is also internal. The site is reachable and resolvable from the computer where `docker-machine` is installed.

### Questions

Which brings me to the questions...

1) Under the hood, what are `dig` and `host` doing differently than both `cURL` and `nslookup`?

2) What could possibly be preventing a browser or `curl` from resolving the URL the way both `host` and `dig` are successfully resolving the name?

### Setup

`dig -v`: `DiG 9.11.1`

`host -v`: `host 9.11.1`

`curl -V`: `curl 7.49.1`

docker version: `Version 17.06.0-ce-mac19 (18663) Channel: stable`

```
 Boot2Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build HEAD : 0672754
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would expect `curl` to us the resolver library which will use the name service providers listed in the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` hosts specification in order.  If this does not include DNS, DNS resolution will not occur.  `nslookup` is not documented to use this file, but from your experience it appears it may.  Often this data is cached by a name service caching daemon.  If the daemon, is failing you may get this kind of issue even if the other configurations are correct.

`host` and `dig` are pure DNS lookup programs. They both resolve names only via DNS.  They will not resolve names using files or other non-DNS providers.  I would expect them to use the information in `/etc/resolv.conf` directly.

Comment: Did you mean `curl` at the very beginning?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Yes, I have updated accordingly.